# Full-Text search for relational database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, full-text-search

I will soon require a full-text search in one of my projects, so I started researching some of the search engines out there.. for instance Azure Search, however... from what I have seen so far, none of the engines are able to search across multiple tables with relationships across those tables.

So for instance.. I cant simply ask the engine to search for the word "red" and then it would "crawl" all the tables(or indexed tables), and return the hit with the possibility for me to step through its relational data..

So for instance.. lets say we have a table called Cars. We also have two other tables, one called Color and another one called Brand.. now Cars has a relation/FK to the table Color and the table Brand.. when I use my search engine I would like to be able to search for all cars with all valid-relational setups that has the color "red", and then be able to get the car(not only the data of the color, but the actual Car-data).

From what I have seen must search engines (Azure Search included), requires me to "flatten" the relational structure of my data into one single record.. which seems strange since that would end up in quite a lot of data and would be a lot harder to "map" back to my data-entities with relations.

So... any ideas of how to do a full-text search through a relational database (in my case the database would be an SQL Server database)?

Br,
Inx

Comment: Take a look at this link which talks about Full Text Search in Azure SQL Database: https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/30/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/. It's in preview currently. See if it suits your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a flattened entity is the best approach, if anything in order to properly score full text searches across multiple tables. What I mean by that is that it is possible to search multiple tables in 1 query (example: `SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(Cars,*,'sedan') join CONTAINSTABLE(Brands,*,'honda') on...`) but the range of the score will vary widely for each search, so calculating a unified score that is reliable is somewhere between extremely difficult to impossible. This is not a problem with a flattened entity.

The flattened entity does not (and should not) replace your existing tables. It should be a separate table in the database. To keep it in sync you can 1) create a job that regularly inserts/updates it or 2) you can take advantage of [change tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb933994.aspx) for something more real-time.

The flattened entity should contain columns that allow you to map back to the other entities. Example of a flattened entity for Cars:

```
Cars_FullText
-------------
CarId   <-- these 3 columns from the Cars table
CarName*
CarDescription
ColorId   <-- these 2 columns from the Colors lookup table
ColorName*
BrandId   <-- these 2 columns from the Brands lookup table
BrandName* ...

* this column is full text indexed
```

Yes, your database will require more storage. Yes, this does add another part to the system. But I think this is the best approach considering the limitations of SQL Server full text indexing and the scores-across-multiple-tables issue I mentioned earlier on.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback :).
Lets say I would go with the "flatten-approach", how would this easiest be implemented?
I guess my question is.. how would one create the json-schema and then also generate the data-rows to index? Is there a framework for this.. or would this all have to be created manually? Would it be possible to do some sort of JOIN to create the all the rows one might want to index? Any suggestions :)?.. I assume  could use reflection to "crawl" my data-models and generate the schema.. but rather use something tested if there is any.

Comment: Guess I should have mentioned that the above comment applies to the Azure Search service..